# Twitter parsing with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I'm newguy in parsing with selenium.
i got a task "you should get 10 Elon Musk's last 10 twitts and show text of it in terminal".
i tried do that like this:

```
import os

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
LOGIN = os.getenv('LOGIN')
PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
IP_ADRESS = os.getenv('FR_IP_ADRESS')
PORT = os.getenv('FR_PORT')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://{LOGIN}:{PASSWORD}@{IP_ADRESS}:{PORT}'
    }
}

try:
    link = 'https://twitter.com/elonmusk'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        options=options,
        seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
    )

    stealth(
        browser,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
    )

    browser.get(link)

    browser.implicitly_wait(20)
    target = browser.find_elements(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="tweet"]'
        )

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

    twits = browser.find_elements(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="tweet"] [data-testid="tweetText"]'
        )

    for twit in twits[::10]:
        print(twit.text)

finally:
    time.sleep(20)
    browser.quit()
```

The first problem is that scroling `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")` dosen't work, but when i used it in the first version of code, it worked normal.
The second problem is that my twitts colector dosen't collect anything or collects different values every next time.
I tried use different methods of scroll, but they either work or don't work. There is similar situation in twtits collector.
I think that the problem could be conect with twitter's work method, but i can't be sure because i have not enough exp in parsing.
I hope you will help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selenium find elements is not working so, we can pass HTML content to BeautifulSoup to Extract tweet text.

here is full script to get first 10 tweet text

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = Options()
#options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\yourusername\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome Beta\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")

driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service, options=options)

try:
    link = 'https://twitter.com/elonmusk'
    driver.get(link)

    tweet_text_elements = []

    # Scroll 5 times to load more tweets
    for _ in range(5):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        time.sleep(2) 

        html_content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

        # Find all elements with 'tweetText'
        tweet_text_elements.extend(soup.find_all('div', {'data-testid': 'tweetText'}))

    # first 10 tweet
    for i, tweet_text_element in enumerate(tweet_text_elements[:10]):
        tweet_text = tweet_text_element.text.strip().replace("\n", "")
        print(f"Tweet {i+1}: {tweet_text}")

finally:
    driver. Quit()
```